Background sync stops in PWA app when user is online in iPhone and user mobile goes in sleep mode or locked or screen turns off
I have created an PWA app in angular. In this app background syncing start on initial load in online mode. This background sync work well when the user iPhone screen is on and he switch to another app and come back. But when user get idle the iPhone goes in sleep mode or locked and the background sync stops. It resumes again when user is turn on the screen. It is happening specifically to iPhone. In android device it works fine.
I tested in different device but in iPhone it is a problem. I am expecting the background sync should continue even when the iPhone is in sleep mode or locked, like it is working for android device.

Not sure when you refer to background sync in your PWA which API you mean, but keep in mind the following APIs currently are NOT supported in Safar on iOS. See browser compatibility table at the end of page.

Background Synchronization API
Background Fetch API
Periodic Background Synchronization API

These facts show me that very likely Apple tries to minimize to implement any background operation apart from the normal app lifecycle. Expect Push API and Notification API.
